# need fix for Could not find gem 'google-protobuf (= 3.23.1)' with platforms 'arm64-darwin-22' in cached gems or installed locally or in gems cached i

Tags: bundler, apple-m2

`Could not find gem 'google-protobuf (= 3.23.1)' with platforms 'arm64-darwin-22', 'x86_64-darwin-19', 'x86_64-darwin-20', 'x86_64-darwin-21', 'x86_64-darwin-22', 'x86_64-linux', 'aarch64-linux' in cached gems or installed locally or in gems cached in vendor/cache.`

`The source contains the following gems matching 'google-protobuf (= 3.23.1)':

- google-protobuf-3.23.1-arm64-darwin
- google-protobuf-3.23.1-x86_64-darwin
- google-protobuf-3.23.1-x86_64-linux`

I think bundler is looking for arm-darwin-22 but google-protobuf provides google-protobuf-3.23.1-arm64-darwin. im expecting bundler to be able to resolve these dependencies. Just upgraded to apple M2 chip and updated bundler to 2.4.14